# iframe html5 chrome safari IE FF

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I need an iframe to be copy/paste on my cms editor, i am trying to calculate the height and width of the content of the iframe dynamically so that iframe takes up the available space without any scrollbars or moveable content. I want iframe to be fixed so that content around it moves. So far this is my code but I can't figure out how do i get rid of scrollable content even if i can hide the scrollbars. Please help!!
this is what it looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      
      header {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      .main {
        flex-grow: 1;
        padding-right: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      .right-panel {
        flex-basis: 300px;
        height: calc(100vh - 110px);
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .footer {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .iframe-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .iframe-container iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
    
 <script>
    // Selecting the iframe element
    var frame = document.getElementById("Iframe");
      
    // Adjusting the iframe height onload event
    frame.onload = function()
    // function execute while load the iframe
    {
      // set the height of the iframe as 
      // the height of the iframe content
      frame.style.height = 
      frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
       

     // set the width of the iframe as the 
     // width of the iframe content
     frame.style.width  = 
      frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth+'px';
          
    }
     </script>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <h2>Body Content</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor nibh vel neque malesuada, nec dictum justo laoreet. Ut pharetra dolor eu odio consequat, ut lobortis ipsum malesuada. Nullam porttitor diam et diam posuere, a euismod urna blandit. Praesent quis tellus sit amet erat posuere iaculis. Maecenas laoreet sapien et justo vulputate, nec consectetur nulla mattis. Etiam fermentum mi ut quam aliquet, quis viverra lorem bibendum. Donec malesuada ex in nibh pellentesque, sit amet fringilla odio maximus. Donec cursus, nulla a aliquet dignissim, quam libero tincidunt purus, at tincidunt quam sapien eu ipsum. Sed bibendum orci quis tellus maximus ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe src="https://9now.nine.com.au/today/competitions/free-fuel-friday-2023" 
          style="width: 100%;border:3px solid black;"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy; 2023 My Website</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

[image]